# Why rectification amplifies signal?

Tags: amplifier, signal-processing, rectifier

why a thermionic valve can amplify an electric signal (for instance, a radio wave or AC), by removing half of its phase? In other words, how is it possible that half-wave rectification can amplify the signal instead of reducing it by half?

Comment: Are you asking how a thermionic valve can be used as an amplifier?

Comment: @gigiux It doesn't amplify the signal, it cut's the sine wave in half, plus the voltage loss from the diode or switch.

Comment: @Gigiux, can you add a schematic that shows a circuit that demonstrates this and then we can discuss it.

Comment: It sounds like you're confusing a simple rectifier with a (triode?) amplifier operating in class B.

Comment: May be related to: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/175474/why-do-rectified-voltage-boosts-after-adding-a-capacitor

Comment: Considering the OP is asking about radio waves: There are such things as reflectance amplifiers, where a one-port device (such as a gunn-diode) can have a negative impedance, resulting in the reflected wave being larger than the incident wave. Using circulators you can then split the two and still provide gain. Perhaps a non-linear impedance, such as a diode, can also achieve this, and do something similar to a class C amplifier?

Answer (score 1):

A thermionic valve (vacuum tube) with two electrodes (anode (plate) and cathode) can be used as a rectifier, but does not amplify a signal.

Other tubes with one or more grids between the anode and cathode can amplify signals, as a small change in voltage on the control grid will cause a change in the current passing between cathode and plate.

Comment: This makes sense, but I read from the history of John Fleming that he employed his thermionic valve to increase the reception of Marconi's radio. I can't add a schematic because I am not an engineer but I am pretty sure Fleming used a diod not a triod.

Comment: Hello, could the rectifier allow better reception? and if yes, how? I quote from some Flemig's biographies "It [the valve] enabled weaker signals to be detected, and for the first time it allowed high-frequency measurements to be made."

Comment: @Gigiux:  I haven't studied Flemings's work, but I suspect that the thermionic valve was more sensitive than the detectors previously used, so could handle weaker signals.

Comment: but that is the point: how did the valve improve the sensitivity?