# Bridge rectifier with filter capacitor

Tags: full-bridge

I have a circuit here for a full-wave bridge rectifier with a Vdc of 18.773V, and I understand it perfectly.

[image: Full Wave Bridge Rectifier]

This is my first time encountering this type of problem. When I started using a capacitor, I began to get confused. What is the reason for the Vdc jumping to 29.661V?

[image: One capacitor]

And now with two capacitors.

In the first scenario, I found it confusing because the voltages across the resistors ranged from a high of 20V to a low of -8V when using two capacitors. Why?

[image: Start]

After 16 seconds, all the voltages settled at 14.9V and -14.9V. Is this due to differences in capacitance?

[image: Vdcs after 16 seconds]

Thank you for your time and patience.

Comment: There's a good answer here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/175474/why-do-rectified-voltage-boosts-after-adding-a-capacitor

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The voltage reads higher with a capacitor because the meter reads the average voltage, with the ripple reduced the average is nearer the peak.

Also, when you added the second capacitor you put it between the negative of the rectifier and ground, so there is no DC return path except through the 10k resistors. You have a weak ground, and uneven loading will cause the voltages to be uneven.

What you have is something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFM4uc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There's no direct DC connection to ground for the the voltages, you have  sort of floating ground that will be dependent on the impedances on each side of the supply.

If what you were attempting to do is make a bipolar supply, the transformer secondary needs a center tap connected to ground. That would give you something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjUEi5.png)</sup>

With a strong ground, loading one side doesn't affect the other.